# How can I install Diablo 3 if I use FileVault?

Tags: diablo-iii, macos

The [official FAQ](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-installation-troubleshooting-mac#10) says that FileVault and FileVault2 are incompatible with Diablo 3. How can I install Diablo 3 on my Mac if my harddrive uses FileVault?

Comment: Blizzard's archive format is incompatible with FileVault due to its [low level nature][1].

I was able to use the following steps to get around this:

  * [Created a new partition][2] of suitable size (I went with 50GB)
  * Moved the installer to that new partition
  * Launched the D3 installer from the new partition
  * Selected a folder on the new partition as the install location

  [1]: http://www.quora.com/Blizzard-Entertainment/What-about-Blizzards-game-install-process-is-incompatible-with-Apples-Filevault
  [2]: http://macs.about.com/od/applications/ss/diskutilitysize.htm

Comment: Grats, now that you have 15 rep you can post the above as an actual answer :)

Comment: @thedagit I don't see how your answer is functionally different than disabling FileVault on the drive or partition you want to install Diablo III on. You can't play Diablo III on a FileVault-enabled partition: creating a new partition without FileVault will of course work, as FileVault wouldn't be enabled where you want to install Diablo III.

Comment: @MarkTrapp It's different in that I did not have to disable the FileVault on my harddrive where I'm already using FileVault. It saves me the trouble of having to copy my encrypted data to unencrypted data and I'm able to keep the same level of security as before for the data I had before.  Basically, I'm able to get the best of both worlds; still using FileVault for all my normal data and I have diablo3 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blizzard's archive format is incompatible with FileVault due to its low level nature. To get around this problem, you need to move the installer to a partition that does not use FileVault. I would also recommend installing it to a partition that does not use FileVault as well, in case later game updates use the MPQ archive format as well.

I was able to use the following steps to get around this:

- Created a new partition of suitable size (I went with 50GB)
- Moved the installer to that new partition
- Created an "Applications" folder on that partition
- Launched the D3 installer from the new partition
- Selected the "Applications" folder on the new parition

This allows you to keep FileVault enabled on your primary partition while also installing Diablo3. That is, you get the best of both worlds at the cost of creating a special partition for Diablo3. This way you do not have to disable FileVault for your entire computer.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't aware of the issues with Diablo 3 and FileVault, but just confirmed that I have FileVault turned on for my primary HD where Diablo 3 is installed.  One difference that I can tell between my setup and yours may be that I turned on FV **after** I had installed Diablo 3.

A few weeks back I installed a new drive in my Mac and the first thing I setup, after running the OSX Lion upgrade was to start the Diablo 3 download and install.  It wasn't till a week later that I realized that I forgot to turn on FileVault and that's when I turned it on.  So it could be that a way around the issue is to have FileVault turned off when installing Diablo 3 and then turning it on afterwards.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if you will have any trouble installing updates.

Comment: Nope, the patch that came out the other day worked fine.  Interestingly enough, the other night, I also installed Diablo 3 on my Macbook (also has FileVault on) and had no problems playing it. Weird that I'm not having any issues.